# How do I remove meta tag for layout?

Tags: grails, groovy, gsp, meta-tags, sitemesh

I have defined a layout, 'mainTemplate' for my grails application. I use `g:layoutHead` (so my pages append their head section to the layouts).

But when I look into the source of my home page, I still get the meta info for the layout.

Though I get my page rendered in the defined template, but I suppose grails should have removed this meta info.

http://grails.org/doc/1.3.x/ref/Tags/layoutHead.html

How do I remove it? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Can you elaborate on *why* you want the `<meta>` tag removed?

Comment: Its not very necessary to remove it, but I hoped it shouldn't have been there, I felt I missed something or it was some bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using the `<meta>` tag to define the layout, it's not easily removable. However, you can use `<g:applyLayout>` in your views to avoid using the `<meta>` tag.

```
<!-- a GSP view, e.g. views/foo/index.gsp -->
<g:applyLayout name="main"><!-- value for "name" is the same as what you'd use in the meta tag -->
  <html>
    <head><title>My Decorated Page</title></head>
    <body>
      Some content
    </body>
  </html>
</g:applyLayout>
```

Essentially what you're doing is removing the `<meta>` tag from your view and then wrapping the contents of the view with the `<g:applyLayout>`.

Admittedly, this is a lot of work; you'd need to update all of your views, and also probably update the scaffolded views in `src/templates` (if you're using scaffolding). To be honest, removing the `<meta>` tag from the final view seems largely unnecessary except for some very exceptional cases (e.g. a naming conflict with "layout", or that you just *have* to prevent those extra ~35 characters from being sent over the wire, which seems pretty micro-optimization-happy to me).

Comment: Thanks Rob, surely that's a help. Its a lot of work though changing it into all my GSPs.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to remove the `<meta>` tag for compliance with our WCAG validator<sup>1</sup>.

I added an item to one of my tag libraries to make it convenient.

```
def wcagValidLayoutHead = {
  def head = request["__sitemesh__page"].head
  out << head.replaceAll(/<meta .*name=['"]layout['"].*\/>/, '')
}
```

And then used it like so:

```
<head>
  <title><g:layoutTitle default="My Valid HTML Page"/></title>
  <my:wcagValidLayoutHead/>
</head>
```

It's a bit of a hack and I'm sure the regex can be improved for speed, but it works.

---

1: I'm not convinced it's actually invalid HTML, but if it makes the validator happy, I can move on to bigger and better problems.